# stop update parent if he has child

Tags: php, pdo

I have list like this

```
John
   Jack
       Husam
   Koko
       Rami
       Loay
```

And I have this function that allow me to **change father of child**, in my case I can change Koko to make him child of Loay.

I want to stop this because he has child, how can I validate this case to **check if he has child then can't change it**, and if he does not has child then I can change his father ?

This is my function

```
public function updateParentId($parentId, $childId)
{
  $statment = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE person SET parent = $parentId WHERE id = $childId");
  $statment->execute();
  $result = $statment->rowCount();
  if($result == "1")
  {
       $message = '<label>successfully</label>';
  }
  else
    {
       $message = '<label>Wrong</label>';
    }
   echo $message;
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to validate anything? You have neither provided such code nor the update call, so helping is really difficult

Comment: First are you understand my problem @NicoHaase ??

Comment: Then please explain what your problem is.

Comment: I can change the father of Loay  for example to John, How can i check if Loay has child or not?? if he has child i want to prevent change his father, and if he don't has child i want to allow change his father @NicoHaase

Comment: @H.Ghass this is where you normalise your db setup with different tables and build relationships based on the that.

Comment: We are very few information but two ideas : 1/ Add an info in database eg. `has_child` that is true or false, so before the change you check if `has_child` is true : is yes, no change, else you change. 2/ Just check if you can find child, if yes no change, else change

Comment: And btw the function if your question just do a select...where is your insert or update?

Comment: @MickaelLeger I' am sorry i updated my code.

Comment: Here is my question how i can check if he find child Sir ?

Answer (score 1):

Following query will return all children below **Koko**(Rami, Loay) in hierarchy.

```
$statment = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, parent FROM (SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY parent, id) sorted, (SELECT @id:=:id) temp WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(parent, @id) > 0 || id = "Loay") AND @id:=CONCAT(@id, ",", id)');
$statment->execute();
$parents = $statment->fetchAll();
foreach ($parents as $value) {
    if ($value['id'] == "Loay") {
        throw new \Exception('Person can not be moved to its children.');
    }
}
```

**Note:** Here I'm not aware of table structure completely. So just given a general example.

> Update Query

```
$statment = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE person SET parent = :parentId WHERE id = :childId");
$statment->execute([":parentId" => $parentId, ":childId" => $childId]);
$result = $statment->rowCount();
```

Comment: This code just prevent me to moved father to its children ? or if he has children i can't moved it to any name in tree ?

Comment: You should use `id` instead of children name (like **Loay** used here) which will be unique for each `person` and there will be no clash even if names of many persons will same.

Comment: He gives me this Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in /var...

Comment: He Indicates to  $statment->execute();